# Structure Confusion

Tags: c, struct, declaration, definition

Its been a while that I am not in touch with the C language, so I was just going through some of the concepts but could not find any good source on structures.

Can anyone please explain

```
struct A
{
   int a;
   char b;
   float c;
};
```

Is this the declaration or the definition of the structure `A`.

Comment: Lol when I ask such questions , I get about 9 down votes xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a declaration.

`struct A;` is a [forward declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) or incomplete declaration.

```
struct A
{
   int a;
   char b;
   float c;
};
```

is complete `struct` declaration.

**[Example](http://ideone.com/JqFhSD)**

Also check [comp.lang.c FAQ list Question 11.5](http://c-faq.com/ansi/structinproto.html)

After forward declaration of `struct`, you can use structure pointers but can not dereference the pointers or use `sizeof` operator or create instances of the `struct`.

After declaration, you can also use `struct` objects, apply the `sizeof` operator etc.

---

**From 6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers** from C11 specs

> 8 The type is incomplete until immediately after the } that terminates
>   the list, and complete thereafter.

And from **6.7.2.3 Tags**

> If a type specifier of the form
>  *struct-or-union identifier* occurs
>   other than as part of one of the above forms, and no other declaration
>   of the identifier as a tag is visible, then it declares an incomplete
>   structure or union type, and declares the identifier as the tag of
>   that type.<sup>131</sup>)
> <sup>131</sup>A similar construction with enum does not exist

---

This should not be confused with `extern struct A aa;` v/s `struct A aa ={/*Some values*/};` which are declaration and definitions of object `aa`.

Comment: And what about these statements **Struct A aa;**       and **Struct bb={//Some values};** Are both of these two statements definitions as extern is default storage class.

Comment: @RohitSaluja `struct A aa;` is declaration of `aa` and `Struct bb={//Some values};` is definition of `bb`. Here OP is interested in declaration and definition of struct itself.

Comment: That's not a definition in C parlance. In C, definitions declare an object and reserve storage, see C99 Section 6.7#5.

Comment: Well if i **Struct A aa** is only a declaration no memory will be allocated for aa rt? But i wrote a code and was able to get the address of aa here http://ideone.com/myirm6

Comment: @RohitSaluja Use `printf("%p\n",(void *)&aa);` as shown [here](http://ideone.com/0nbGFd)

Comment: You are confused; `struct a ={//Some values};` is even a syntax error (not due to the comment, but because you can't assign to a **tag** name.)

Comment: @Mohit Your explained the answer very well but I have one more doubt now, What is the difference between **Forward declaration and declaration**, and is there anything like **backward declaration** :p ?     And also Since the structure by itself is only declared so it doesn't occupy any memory , It is the structure objects which occupies the memory rt ?

Comment: @RohitSaluja If you do forward declaration, compiler knows there is a structure with name `A`, but the members of this structure are not known. You can pass pointers to this structure around (An address pointing to object of this structure), but can not actually access the members or check the size of structure. (Also google for pimpl idiom for use of forward declaration). After structure declaration, you can use the structure(dereference, access members). There is nothing like backward declaration. Yes, you are right, structure declaration does not occupy any memory, the objects of struct do.

Comment: But the declaration does not provide any memory space then how come we are able to pass pointers to the structure if it is only declared and no memory is being allocated to it ?

Comment: Because the tag name is no more unknown to the compiler and pointer just specifies the start of memory. Compiler can manage without knowing the actual type, content and size of block being pointed to by that pointer. In C you can have pointers to incomplete type. This makes the famous `struct node` used for linked list and tree possible.

Comment: Thanks for explaining my every question :(y) :)

Comment: You are most welcome. I am glad if my writings helped you. Also read the answer of @Jens carefully. To answer your original question, his answer is written way better.

Answer (score 11):

It declares a struct with the struct tag `A` and the specified members. It does neither define nor reserve any storage for an object.

From the C99 Standard, 6.7 Declarations:

> **Semantics**
>
> 5 A declaration specifies the interpretation and attributes of a set of
>   identifiers. A *definition* of an identifier is a declaration for that
>   identifier that:
>
> — for an object, causes storage to be reserved for
>   that object;
>
> — for a function, includes the function body; (footnote 98)
>
> — for an
>   enumeration constant or typedef name, is the (only) declaration of the
>   identifier.

For a definition, you would need to provide an object identifier before the final semicolon:

```
struct A
{
   int a;
   char b;
   float c;
} mystruct;
```

To also initialize mystruct you would write

```
struct A
{
   int a;
   char b;
   float c;
} mystruct = { 42, 'x', 3.14 };
```

Comment: your's answer is opposite to Mohit answer. So what is the correct answer ? :/

Comment: @Mohit fixed his answer.

Comment: @RohitSaluja Mine is, because C is defined by an international standard, and I quote the relevant chapter and verse. All books on C use this terminology as well.

Comment: A slight correction, `struct A { ... } mystruct;` is not always definition in `C`. Check [this example](http://ideone.com/5OBEi4) where there are multiple declarations and just one definition.